# Extrapolating between two dataframes (rounding issues)

Tags: python, pandas

I am having issues trying to extrapolate between two dataframes

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame([(50,100),(150,250),(250,300)], columns=['a','b'])
 df2 = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(500,600)], columns=['a','b'])
```

I tried

```
cagr_7 = (df2/df1)**(1/5) - 1
f = lambda c: c + c*cagr_7
```

But often times the inbetween years don't make sense due to having report every year.  Is there another extrapolation option, maybe taking the difference and applying it across the years?

I am trying to extrapolate between 5 different years.  Example 2016 to 2021.  Each dataframe is a year.

I need help please.

Comment: Where do you have years in these dataframes?

Comment: every dataframe is a year

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, this may be a start:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([(50,100),(150,250),(250,300)], columns=['a','b'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([(100,200),(300,400),(500,600)], columns=['a','b']) 

pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=[2016,2021])\ #concat the datafrmaes using keys to define year
  .unstack()\                            #reshape dataframe
  .reindex(np.arange(2016,2022,1))\      #reindex adding years to interpolate to
  .interpolate(method='index')\          #interpolate using method index
  .stack(0)\                             #reshape dataframe to desired format
  .T
```

Output:

```
    2016          2017          2018          2019          2020          2021       
       a      b      a      b      a      b      a      b      a      b      a      b
0   50.0  100.0   60.0  120.0   70.0  140.0   80.0  160.0   90.0  180.0  100.0  200.0
1  150.0  250.0  180.0  280.0  210.0  310.0  240.0  340.0  270.0  370.0  300.0  400.0
2  250.0  300.0  300.0  360.0  350.0  420.0  400.0  480.0  450.0  540.0  500.0  600.0
```